# How do I change Windows 10 hotkeys?

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

I recently noticed Windows 10's virtual desktop feature.
Using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>+ and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> is too much effort to change desktops.
I want to create a hotkey so that simply pressing <kbd>page-up</kbd> or <kbd>page-down</kbd> will switch between desktops like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>+ and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> does.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I added info on how to avoid clicking the script every time you start/restart your computer, if you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows does not allow to remap those keys so you will need third-party software to do this. AutoHotkey can do it easily.

Install [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/)

Save following two lines as `remap.ahk` (make sure it is not <strike>`remap.ahk.txt`</strike>)

```
PgDn::Send ^#{Left}
PgUp::Send ^#{Right}
```

Now right-click the resulting file and select `Run script`

<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> should now switch desktops

However you will be unable to use a normal <kbd>PageUp</kbd> / <kbd>PageDown</kbd> function at all as long as the script is running

To stop it, expand notification area ("system tray") hidden icons area, locate a green square with white `H` on it, right click and select `Exit`

For more info refer to [AutoHotkey documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm).

You will need to run the script every time you log in. To start it automatically, right-click the script file and select `Compile Script`. This should produce a new file with same name in the same folder as your script. Now press <kbd>⊞ Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type: `shell:startup` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. A `startup` folder should open. Place the new (compiled) file into this folder.