# How do I assign "Switch to Virtual Desktop 1 (2/3/4)" to F1 (F2/F3/F4) in Windows 11?

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys, windows-11, virtual-desktop

My fastest way of working is not to have 4 monitors (swiveling or rotating the head takes at least half a second) but to have fixed Virtual Desktops for specific tasks. So I know "Webbrowser: 3rd Desktop". To switch there I do not want to dislocate by left fingers nor do I want to use both hands (Win+Ctrl+...). And I *know* where I want to go and not first try Left once, then Right twice.

**So: How do I assign "Switch to Virtual Desktop 1" fo "F1", and to F2, F3 and F4 respectivly? It should not be a relative action (one to the left or right) but absolute ("the one where I always have my browser").**

I don't mind loosing "Help" on F1, "Rename" on F2. But as a bonus reassigning those to, say, Win+F1 and Win+F2 would be nice.

Another bonus would be no have a convenient way to send the focused Window to a specific Virtual Desktop. Opening the Task Switcher and then using Drag and Drop is not convenient; especially, if I need to switch to the Virtual Desktop first and reopenign the Task Switcher again. I imagine either a hotkey (absolute, like "Send to Desktop 3", Win+Ctrl+Shift+F1 maybe), or a Taskbar- or Titlebar-action. That's a lot, I know, but *that* would be very convienient.

---

**Things I tried:**

I looked into *AutoHotKey* but I did not see a way how to get to an absolute Virtual Desktop. [This one](https://github.com/searene/windows-desktop-switcher) did work actually, but was very slow. Because it cycles through the desktops dynamically it seems. So to get from Desktop 1 to Desktop 4 takes seconds.

[Here](https://superuser.com/a/1512798/51986) it says "quick switch" to an absolute desktop might be impossible, but that part is really important to me. And [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1107114/how-do-i-change-windows-10-hotkeys) also comes close using AutoHotKey, but relative again.

Comment: Sounds like you need to install a third party powershell module, write the approapriate ps1 script for switch to desktop 1, switch to desktop 2 etc... then use autohotkey to bind F1, F2 to each individual desktop switching script. Have you seen this one by MScholtes?

https://github.com/MScholtes/PSVirtualDesktop

Answer (score 0):

Try the AutoHotKey Github project of
[Windows 10 Virtual Desktop Enhancer](https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer).

You need to download the project as a Zip file, unpack to a folder,
then double-click the script `virtual-desktop-enhancer.ahk`
(assuming AutoHotKey is already installed).

Use by default the combination of
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad-key</kbd>
to switch to the virtual desktop of this number.

Keyboard shortcuts can be modified in the file `settings.ini`.